# Joi validations - if this and that, then. Else

Tags: javascript, validation, jsonschema, joi

I'm trying to apply multiple validations to a Joi schema that checks the value of two keys and validates a final key based on the result.

Using the example body of below, I want to check the field of channel. This could be either `LOCAL` or `GLOBAL`.

```
{
    "channel":"LOCAL",
    "beneficiary": {
        "currency": "GBP",
        "accountNumber": "12345678"
    }
}
```

If LOCAL and the beneficiary.currency is GBP, then the following should apply: `Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]{8}$/).required()`

If GLOBAL and the beneficiary.currency is also GBP, then the following should apply: `Joi.string().regex(/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}([0-9]|[A-Z])+([0-9A-Z]+){10,31}$/).required()`

However this needs to work for a matrix of many possibilities as per the following +n amount of supported currencies.

| TYPE | CURRENCY | REGEX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GLOBAL | USD | ^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}([0-9]|[A-Z])+([0-9A-Z]+){10,31}$ |
| LOCAL | USD | ^[0-9A-Z]{1,45}$ |
| GLOBAL | GBP | ^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}([0-9]|[A-Z])+([0-9A-Z]+){10,31}$ |
| LOCAL | GBP | ^[0-9]{8}$ |
| GLOBAL | AUD | ^[A-Za-z0-9]{0,9}$ |
| LOCAL | AUD | ^[0-9]{1,7}$ |
| GLOBAL | SGD | ^[A-Za-z0-9]+$ |
| LOCAL | SGD | ^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,50}$ |

I've found I can use the following but doesn't scale across the matrix of possible options:

```
     accountNumber: Joi.string().when(Joi.ref('...channel', {
       is: 'LOCAL',
       then: Joi.when(Joi.ref('currency'), { is: 'GBP', then: Joi.string().regex(/^[0-9]{8}$/).required() })
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `oneOf` for this use case:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "channel": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "GLOBAL"
        },
        "beneficiary": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/beneficiary-GLOBAL-USD"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "channel": {
          "type": "string",
          "const": "LOCAL"
        },
        "beneficiary": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/beneficiary-LOCAL-USD"
        }
      }
    }    
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "beneficiary-GLOBAL-USD": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "accountNumber": {
          "pattern": "^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}([0-9]|[A-Z])+([0-9A-Z]+){10,31}$"
        },
        "currency": {
          "const": "USD"
        }
      }
    },
    "beneficiary-LOCAL-USD": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "accountNumber": {
          "pattern": "^[0-9A-Z]{1,45}$"
        },
        "currency": {
          "const": "USD"
        }
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

If you also put the single sub-schemas as `$ref` in separate definitions is up to you. But I am afraid you can't get much less verbose.

Comment: The duplicated `"type": "string"`s could be pulled out into the top level schema. It would also be smart to add `"required":["channel"]` -- otherwise if that property is missing, all of the `if` clauses will fire, which will cause the overall schema to fail because of multiple `oneOf`s passing, but with more cryptic error messages than what would be produced by a `required`.

Comment: Maybe. But if channel is not required we can add one sub-schema to oneOf that covers the case if no channel property is present.